# .replace() arbitrary text with new DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a block of untagged text in a div.  I want to parse the text and replace certain key words with new form elements that include handlers.  One example is that when I see the text "Date:________ "I want to replace that with a new input field, give it a unique id, and then attach a .datepicker() handler to it.

Given sample text:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Date:________ Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. *

I have tried the following:

```
$("#textdiv").replace(/Date:________/g, "<input type='text' id='textid_123'/>");  
$("#textid_123").datepicker();
```

And while it creates the input box, it does not attach the datepicker() handler.   This doesn't really surprise me and I'm guessing that JQuery is not aware of the DOM modification.

If my "Date" was wrapped in a  or another tag, this would be trivial.   Is there a way to replace plain text with new DOM elements that are visible to JQuery?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Does this code really create an input box? jQuery objects don't have a `replace` method, so I'm at a loss to understand how your code doesn't produce an error. Are you using a library that supplies the `replace` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replace is not a function`.

You should replace the innerHTML of your element, like this:

```
$("#textdiv").html( 
   $("#textdiv").html().replace(/Date:________/g, "<input type='text' id='textid_123'/>") 
); 

console.log( $('#textid_123') );  // yup, it's there, so .datepicker should work
```

BTW: you use `/g` flag in the regex which means you expect to replace more than one instance of `Date: ___`. In this case you shouldn't use a hardcoded `id` on the new input element, because ids have to be unique.

http://jsfiddle.net/hfxvoL56/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that jQuery doesn't pick up the content change, as the content is changed before the `.datepicker` invocation. The problem is that `.replace()` is not a valid jQuery method. Rather replace the HTML content like this:

```
var content = $("#textdiv").html().replace(/Date:________/g, "<input type='text' id='textid_123'/>");
$("#textdiv").html(content);
```

Then you can call the other methods. [Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82fzq94u/2/)